# =FILTER an inverse result of a partial string match in Excel

Tags: excel, search, filter, excel-formula

**Summary**

I am attempting to filter out a dataset within Excel using `=FILTER`. I would like to search the dataset for a partial string, and filter these results out.

**Current Progress**

I am aware of the use of `<>` within =`FILTER` to omit results. My current method to find the string is to use `ISNUMBER(SEARCH("postmaster",A:A))` to find all results that have "postmaster" within the cell contents. I have attempted to combine both uses, into the following:

`=FILTER(A:A,(A:A<>"foo@bar.com")*(A:A<>0)*(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("postmaster",A:A))))`
Currently, this removes all results with "foo@bar.com" in column A, but then only shows those that contain "postmaster". I am trying to invert this, so it instead filters OUT any that contain postmaster. I want to combine the `ISNUMBER` / `SEARCH` logic with the `<>` exclude logic. Is this possible?

**Conclusion**
I am aware of the premise, but am unable to put them together. I'd appreciate any help in doing this. I am using MSO 365, version 2108. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After further tinkering, I found the solution. This was to wrap the `ISNUMBER` `SEARCH` within a `=NOT` statement, to invert the output.

The new working formula is:

`=FILTER(A:A,(A:A<>"foo@bar.com")*(A:A<>0)*(NOT(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("postmaster",A:A)))))`

If anyone wants to exclude results from a partial string match, they can use the following example:

`=FILTER(DATA:DATA,NOT(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("STRINGTOSEARCH",DATA:DATA))))`

Hopefully this helps someone else in the future!

Comment: Or: `=FILTER(DATA:DATA,ISERROR(FIND("STRINGTOSEARCH",DATA:DATA)))`